# Using react and communicate with backend

Tags: node.js, reactjs, rest, api, express

so im trying to create a simple fullstack app (movies board) to learn react but im having some questions/doubts. Im used to create backend mvc app's with express. So for react i need to create a RESTful API right? if yes how can i protect the api against "public use"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to implement some kind of authorization to secure the API. 
Try to use [OAuth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OAuth)